# Send a MouseEvent to a NSView (WebView) from code

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nsevent

i am trying to send mouseevent (MouseClick or RightMouseClick) to a NSView... in my case a WebView, that contains a loaded Website. I want to script some clicks on links etc. How is it possible to create a NSEvent and send it to the WebView to perform clicks?

Thanks a lot

ksman

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit late; maybe you found it, maybe you didn't.  I recently had to figure this out, though, so I'll document it here and hopefully help someone.

```
NSPoint where;
where.x = x;
where.y = y;
NSView* resp = [someView hitTest:where];
NSEventType evtType = NSLeftMouseDown;
NSEvent *mouseEvent = [NSEvent mouseEventWithType:evtType
                                         location:where
                                    modifierFlags:nil
                                        timestamp:GetCurrentEventTime()
                                     windowNumber:0
                                          context:[o->helper context]
                                      eventNumber:nil
                                       clickCount:1 
                                         pressure:nil];
[resp mouseDown:mouseEvent];
```